# How to display Java Timer on a separate J Frame Form label?

Tags: java, swing, oop, count

i have a question , i have this timer code in java that when its executed it displays a count down timer on its own JFrame label, what i want to do is to display this timer on another JFrame form label without having to move the code to other classes.

I hope you can help me with this thanks lot guys .

this is the code for the Timer class:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class TimerExample extends JFrame {

   final JLabel label;
   Timer countdownTimer;
   int timeRemaining = 10;

   public TimerExample() {
      setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      setSize(200, 200);
      label = new JLabel(String.valueOf(timeRemaining), JLabel.CENTER);
      getContentPane().add(label);

      countdownTimer = new Timer(1000, new CountdownTimerListener());
      setVisible(true);
      countdownTimer.start();
   }

   class CountdownTimerListener implements ActionListener {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         if (--timeRemaining > 0) {
            label.setText(String.valueOf(timeRemaining));
         } else {
            label.setText("Time's up!");
            countdownTimer.stop();
         }
      }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            new TimerExample();
         }
      });
   }

}
```

thanks

Comment: Can you give more detail about your problem? What exactly are you trying to do and why? Will you have a main window from which you wish to launch another window (usually a dialog) that shows your count-down timer? Also, usually in situations like these, you first post your code attempt to solve this problem and then show any error messages or exceptions and describe any behavioral problems. This way we'll know exactly what you may be doing wrong and how to better help  you.

Comment: This code wouldn't even compile; the constructor contains code which seems to assume this class extends `JFrame`, but as written it does not. What is your question, exactly -- how to make this not depend on `JFrame`? Looks like you're already halfway there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here it is,

Following is my TestTimer class which accepts a JLabel as input

```
public class TestTimer {
     private JLabel label;
     Timer countdownTimer;
     int timeRemaining = 10;

     public TestTimer(JLabel passedLabel) {
        countdownTimer = new Timer(1000, new CountdownTimerListener());
        this.label = passedLabel;
        countdownTimer.start();
     }

      class CountdownTimerListener implements ActionListener {
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
             if (--timeRemaining > 0) {
                 label.setText(String.valueOf(timeRemaining));
              } else {
                 label.setText("Time's up!");
                 countdownTimer.stop();
              }
          }
      }
  }
```

And here is another Main class which is actually extending a JFrame and showing a label in it,

```
public class TimerJFrame extends JFrame{    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JLabel label;

    public TimerJFrame() {
     setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         setSize(200, 200);
         label = new JLabel("10", JLabel.CENTER);
         getContentPane().add(label);
         new TestTimer(label);
         setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            new TimerJFrame();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Second Code passes a created JLabel to first class and first class uses it to show timer.

Comment: Thanks alot Rahul it helped alot .

Comment: Tried this and added it to a JFrame. TImer does not work, the number remains to be 10

Answer (score 2):

You need to follow following steps,

1. Modify TimerExample constructor to accept JLabel. And initialize JLabel of TimerExample class with passwd JLabel
2. Pass JLabel from other JFrame class.
3. Remove main method from this as it will not be required.

Bu first step here, constructor will accept predefined JLabel from other classes and use those to display timer.

Comment: i have a logging window, a main window and the TimerExample class, when i click enter on the logging window the main window will show up and thats where i want the timer to appear

Comment: im trying to set a label in the main window to = to the label in the timer class but it doesnt seem to work at some stage the program freezes :

Comment: Pass JLabel from your main window to TimerExample class as I told, so that TimerExample class will update label you passed.

Comment: I am giving you +1, on both the answers, since last time i saw this answer I wanted to upvote, but I went somewhere and I missed, now I came back to this thread to upvote this, but looking at the example you had given on the other answer, I am forced to upvote both of them :-)

Comment: @RahulBorkar : You are most Welcome and Keep Smiling :-)